# UIImagePickerController to select image or video

Tags: ios, image, video, picker

I want the user to be able to select image or video at the same time.The code below allows me to only select video not an image.

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
        //picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you have use ALAsset library classes and use your own custom UI to display the assets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Comment: can you tell me how to use it